# how to get the sharepoint .xml using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, sharepoint

I wanna to parse the xml in Sharepoint using js, but js can only load client-side file, what I gonna do?

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery built-in functionnality with `parseXML`

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/